# How to submit user input and remove question once entered?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to figure out how to capture user input on a number of questions (just for local purposes, not sending to a server), verify whether each answer was correct or not, and then remove that question and add the next question to be answered, and so on. I have gotten close with a few tries but am now stuck. I am using vanilla JS and html.

```js
var firstQ = document.getElementById("first-q");
var secondQ = document.getElementById("second-q");
var thirdQ = document.getElementById("third-q");
var field1 = document.getElementById("field-1");
var field2 = document.getElementById("field-2");
var field3 = document.getElementById("field-3");

field1.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  function questionOne() {
    var answer1 = document.getElementById("first-q").value;
    if (answer1.toUpperCase() === "YES" || answer1.toUpperCase() === "YEAH") {
      alert("good answer");
      field1.classList.remove("active");
      field2.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      alert("wrong answer");
    }
  }
  return false;
});

field2.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  function questionTwo() {
    var answer2 = document.getElementById("second-q").value;
    if (answer2.toUpperCase() === "YES" || answer2.toUpperCase() === "YEAH") {
      alert("good answer");
      field2.classList.remove("active");
      field3.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      alert("wrong answer");
    }
  }
  return false;
});

field3.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  function questionThree() {
    var answer3 = document.getElementById("third-q").value;
    if (answer3.toUpperCase() === "YES" || answer3.toUpperCase() === "YEAH") {
      alert("good answer");
      field3.classList.remove("active");
    } else {
      alert("wrong answer");
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="index.html" method="post">
  <fieldset class="active" id="field-1">
    <label>Is the sky blue?</label>
    <input type="text" id="first-q" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="field-2">
    <label>Are you a human?</label>
    <input type="text" id="second-q" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="field-3">
    <label>Is grass (usually) green?</label>
    <input type="text" id="third-q" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "user input on a number of questions"? Are you going to keep the answers in local storage or something else?

Comment: doesn't `type="submit"` submit the whole form? but what i understood is you want to check is individual questions. remove them if their answer is correct, right?

Comment: It looks like you are getting pretty close, as the comment above states, submit may not be what you are after here. Instead, use a click event. On click, you would get the value entered into the text field, and then do the validation / hide the current field and show the new one.

Answer (score 1):

A little different answer, but it is a little less code really, and you can add a bunch of other question and answers much more easily because it is using classes and not id's and an array for the answers.  It should work with just hiding the elements.  Probably will break if you "remove" the DOM elements.

```js
var sets = document.getElementsByClassName('question');

Array.from(sets).forEach(function(value,index) {

 value.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var answer = this.previousElementSibling.value;
    checkAnswer(index, answer);
  return false;
 });
});

var answerlist = [["YES", "BLUE"], ["YES", "HUMAN"], ["YES", "GREEN"] ];

function checkAnswer(questionnumber, answer) {
 let answers = answerlist[questionnumber];
  let correct = false;
  
  answers.some(function(value,index) {
   if (answer.toUpperCase() === value || answer.toUpperCase() === value) {
      alert("good answer");
      correct = true;
      return true;
    }
 });
  
 if (correct === false) alert("wrong answer");
  sets[questionnumber].style.display = "none";
  if (questionnumber < sets.length - 1) {
  sets[questionnumber].nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
  alert("done");
  }
}
```

```css
.question {
  display:none;
}
fieldset.active {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="index.html" method="post">
<fieldset class="active question">
  <label>Is the sky blue?</label>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off">  
  <button type="submit" value="Submit Answer">submit answer</button>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="question">
  <label>Are you a human?</label>
  <input type="text"  autocomplete="off"> 
  <button type="submit" value="Submit Answer">submit answer</button>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="question">
  <label>Is grass (usually) green?</label>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off">
  <button type="submit" value="Submit Answer">submit answer</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This Might help you https://jsfiddle.net/w19nvftL/

CSS

```
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

HTML

```
<form class="active" id="field-1">
  <label>Is the sky blue?</label>
  <input type="text" id="first-q" autocomplete="off">  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
</form>
<form id="field-2" class="hide">
  <label>Are you a human?</label>
  <input type="text" id="second-q" autocomplete="off"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
</form>
<form id="field-3" class="hide">
  <label>Is grass (usually) green?</label>
  <input type="text" id="third-q" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
</form>

<span id="greets" class="hide">Congratulations</span>
```

JS

```
var firstQ = document.getElementById("first-q");
var secondQ = document.getElementById("second-q");
var thirdQ = document.getElementById("third-q");
var field1 = document.getElementById("field-1");
var field2 = document.getElementById("field-2");
var field3 = document.getElementById("field-3");

field1.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
debugger;
e.preventDefault();
  var answer1 = document.getElementById("first-q").value;
  if ( answer1.toUpperCase() === "YES" || answer1.toUpperCase() === "YEAH") {
    alert("good answer");
   field1. classList.add("hide");
    field2.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    alert("wrong answer");
  }
return false;
});

field2.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var answer2 = document.getElementById("second-q").value;
  if ( answer2.toUpperCase() === "YES" || answer2.toUpperCase() === "YEAH") {
    alert("good answer");    
   field2. classList.add("hide");
    field3.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    alert("wrong answer");

}
return false;
});

field3.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var answer3 = document.getElementById("third-q").value;
  if ( answer3.toUpperCase() === "YES" || answer3.toUpperCase() === "YEAH") {
    alert("good answer");

   field3.classList.add("hide");
   document.getElementById("greets").classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    alert("wrong answer");
  }
return false;
});
```

Comment: That fiddle is a good example, I would suggest include the Javascript in your example and explaining how and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to make a simple quiz, I would create a Constructor like my QuizMaker. You can easily create your own little quizzes with it.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
var doc, bod, I, aC, rC, special, unspecial, QuizMaker;
addEventListener('load', function(){
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
aC = function(element, className){
  var s = element.className.split(/\s+/), n = s.indexOf(className);
  if(n === -1){
    s.push(className); element.className = s.join(' ').trim();
  }
  return function(className, text){
    return aC(element, className, text);
  }
}
rC = function(element, className){
  var s = element.className.split(/\s+/), n = s.indexOf(className);
  if(n !== -1){
    s.splice(n, 1); element.className = s.join(' ').trim();
  }
  return function(className, text){
    return rC(element, className, text);
  }
}
special = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
unspecial = function(str){
  return str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&').replace(/&apos;/g, "'").replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&lt;/g, '<').replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
}
QuizMaker = function(){
  this.quiz = []; this.questionNum = 0; this.results = [];
  this.qa = function(question, answersArray){
    var o = {question:question, answers:answersArray};
    if(!(answersArray instanceof Array))o.answers = [answersArray];
    this.quiz.push(o);
    return this;
  }
  this.shuffle = function(){
    this.quiz.sort(function(){
      return 0.5 - Math.random();
    });
    return this;
  }
  this.ask = function(){
    var q = this.quiz[this.questionNum];
    if(q === undefined){
      return undefined;
    }
    return q.question;
  }
  this.answer = function(answer){
    var n = this.questionNum++, q = this.quiz[n];
    if(q !== undefined){
      var x = new RegExp(answer, 'i');
      for(var i=0,r=false,a=q.answers,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
        if(a[i].toString().match(x)){
          r = true; break;
        }
      }
      this.results.push({question:n, answer:answer, correct:r});
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.reset = function(){
    this.questionNum = 0; this.results.splice(0);
    return this;
  }
}
var qz = new QuizMaker, quiz = I('quiz'), question = I('question'), answer = I('answer'), next = I('next'), out = I('out'), output = I('output');
var retake = I('retake'), asked, res = [], complete;
qz.qa('How many feet in a mile?', 5280).qa('How many teaspoons in a tablespoon?', 3).qa('How many inches in a yard?', 36).qa('If you were going down the road at 60 miles per hour, how long would it take to go one mile?', ['One minute', '1 minute', '1 min']).shuffle();
question.innerHTML = special(qz.ask());
function goNext(){
  if(complete){
    return false;
  }
  qz.answer(answer.value.trim()); answer.value = ''; asked = qz.ask();
  if(asked === undefined){
    qz.results.forEach(function(o, i){
      res.push(i+1+': '+special(qz.quiz[o.question].question)+'<br />'+special(o.answer)+' = '+o.correct);
    });
    output.innerHTML = res.join('<hr />'); aC(quiz, 'hide'); rC(out, 'hide'); complete = true;
  }
  else{
    question.innerHTML = special(asked);
  }
}
next.onclick = goNext;
answer.onkeyup = function(e){
  if(e.key === 'Enter')goNext();
}
retake.onclick = function(){
  qz.reset().shuffle(); complete = false; question.innerHTML = special(qz.ask()); aC(out, 'hide'); rC(quiz, 'hide'); res.splice(0);
}
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  position:relative; background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
input[type=text]{
  width:calc(100% - 54px); padding:5px; border:0; border-radius:5px;
}
#next{
  margin-left:4px;
}
input[type=button]{
  cursor:pointer; padding:5px 7px;
}
#next{
  width:50px;
}
#content>*{
  margin-bottom:4px;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
#retake{
 display:block; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <div class='hide' id='out'><div id='output'></div><input id='retake' type='button' value='retake' /></div>
    <div id='quiz'>
      <div id='question'></div>
      <input id='answer' type='text' value='' /><input id='next' type='button' value='next' />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```